# CircleCI branch build failing but tag build succeeds

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

I am building my project on CircleCI and I have a build job that looks like this:

```
  build:
    <<: *defaults
  steps:
    - checkout
    - setup_remote_docker
    - run:
        name: Install pip
        command: curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py && sudo python get-pip.py
    - run:
        name: Install AWS CLI
        command: curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip" && unzip awscli-bundle.zip && sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
    - run:
        name: Login to Docker Registry
        command: aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1 | sh
    - run:
        name: Install Dep
        command: curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golang/dep/master/install.sh | sh
    - run:
        name: Save Version Number
        command: echo "export VERSION_NUM=${CIRCLE_TAG}.${CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM}" > deployment/dev/.env
    - run:
        name: Build App
        command: source deployment/dev/.env && docker-compose -f deployment/dev/docker-compose.yml build
    - run:
        name: Test App
        command: |
          git config --global url."https://${GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN} :x-oauth-basic@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
          dep ensure
          go test -v ./...
    - run:
        name: Push Image
        command: |
          if [[ "${CIRCLE_TAG}" =~ ^v[0.9]+(\.[0-9]+)*-[a-z]*$ ]]; then
            source deployment/dev/.env
            docker-compose -f deployment/dev/docker-compose.yml push
          else
            echo 'No tag, not deploying'
          fi
    - persist_to_workspace:
        root: .
        paths:
          - deployment/*
          - tools/*
```

When I push a change to a branch, the build fails every time with `Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at ... - is it running?` when it reaches the Build App step of the build job.

Please help me figure out why branch builds are failing but tag builds are not.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are hitting this docker-compose bug: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6050

The bug reports a misleading error (the one you're getting) when an image name in the docker-compose file is invalid.

If you use an environment variable for the image name or image tag, and that variable is set from a branch name, then it would fail on some branches, but not others.

Comment: I've run into that problem before, but that's not what this one was. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was occurring on the `Save Version Number` step. Sometimes that version would be `.${CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM}` since no tag was passed. Docker dislikes these tags starting with `.`, so I added a conditional check to see if `CIRCLE_TAG` was empty, and if it was, use some default version: `v0.1.0-build`.